# maven dependency:tree log: version1 compile (version managed from version2)

Tags: java, maven, solrj

1. I faced a problem with dependency:tree. It troubled me a few days.
   I defined solr-solrj with version 6.6.0 in my pom.xml in one of my modules named A as below:
   `<dependency>
       <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
       <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
       <version>6.6.0</version>
   </dependency>`
2. Another module named B dependencies on module A. when I run `mvn dependency:tree -Dverbose -Dincludes=org.apache.solr:solr-solrj`, the console appears `org.apache.solr:solr-solrj:jar:5.5.3:compile (version managed from 6.6.0)`. I find all the pom.xml, I haven't defined the 5.5.3 version. And I haven't found any jar dependencies on 5.5.3 version transitively in my project.
3. What's the meaning of `5.5.3:compile (version managed from 6.6.0` ? And why 5.5.3 version appeared in my project?
4. [image: 1]

[image: 2]

pic1 is that I use idea to show dependencies. pic2 is I clicked solrj jump to pom.xml.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Either the pom for module B or the parent pom for module B includes a `<dependencyManagement>` section. Dependency management is used in maven to centralize the versions used for jars. It is likely overriding the version of **solr-solrj** you defined to be version 5.5.3. Dependency management functions in two main ways. You are probably experiencing what is described in section 2. Please see the conclusion for a summary specific to your question.

## 1. It is a central place for defining versions of dependencies.

So when an artifact version is defined in the `<dependencyManagement>` section you can declare the dependency in your pom without defining the version, and the version defined in `<dependencyManagement>` will be used automatically.

### Example 1

Let's say your parent pom defined the following

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.mememe</groupId>
      <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.12</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then if you define the following in your pom

```
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.mememe</groupId>
    <artifactId>mylib</artifactId>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Your project will automatically use version 1.1.12 as defined in the `<dependencyManagement>` section of your parent pom.

## 2. Overriding the versions of transitive dependencies.

If you have an artifact version defined in your `<dependencyManagement>` and one of your dependencies has a transitive dependency on the same artifact, the version of the artifact defined in your `<dependencyManagement>` section is used automatically.

### Example 2

Let's say this artifact

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.youyou</groupId>
  <artifactId>yourlib</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Has this transitive dependency

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.morestuff</groupId>
  <artifactId>morelib</artifactId>
  <version>2.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Now let's say our parent pom defines this `<dependencyManagement>` section

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.morestuff</groupId>
      <artifactId>morelib</artifactId>
      <version>2.5.2</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then if you define this dependency in your pom

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.youyou</groupId>
  <artifactId>yourlib</artifactId>
  <version>3.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven will override **yourlib**'s dependency on **morelib** version 2.0.0 with **morelib** version 2.5.2.

## Conclusion

Specific to your question, someone has defined a `<dependencyManagement>` section like the following in the pom or parent pom of module B:

```
<dependencyManagement>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.solr</groupId>
      <artifactId>solr-solrj</artifactId>
      <version>5.5.3</version>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Since **solr-solrj** is a dependency of module A and mondule A is a dependency of module B. Dependency management is overriding the version of **solr-solrj** to be 5.5.3 . You should speak with the person who added this dependencyManagement configuration in your project, there is likely a good reason why they only wanted version 5.5.3 to be used.

## Docs

See more details in the official maven docs [here](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html#Dependency_Management).

Comment: yeah, you're right. I found version 5.5.3 defined in spring-boot-dependencies pom.xml. And spring-boot-dependencies defined in module B parents' dependencyManagement.

Comment: Thanks for such a good explanation, saved my time, I also found dependency management which is causing this.

Comment: I've a similar problem where i see ` org.freemarker:freemarker:jar:2.3.31:compile (version managed from 2.3.32)` but there is no dependencyManagement section in any of my poms